# Question involving disjoint open sets in $k$ topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}_k$ denote the topology, whose basis elements are of the form $(a,b)$ and $(a,b)-K$,where $k=\{\frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Find the closure of $\{\frac{-1}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and answer the question:Is it possible to find disjoint open sets $U,V$ in $\mathbb{R}_k$ such that $0 \in U$ and $K \subset V$.

Answer:the closure of  $\{\frac{-1}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$=$\{\frac{-1}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$ since any open set containing $0$, must contain points in $\{\frac{-1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.No it is not possible to find such sets $U$ and $V$, since $U$ would necessarily contain irrationals between $0$ and the endpoint $b$ of its open interval of the form $(a,b)$ or $(a,b)-K$, and $V$ must be an interval of the form $(a,b)$, where for the purposes of this problem it suffices to assume $V=(0,b),b>1$ which would contain the irrational points as well.

Would this be the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sorry about that, I meant $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the closure of $\left\{-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$.

The second part, however, needs a good bit of work. In particular, you cannot assume that $V$ has the form $(0,b)$ for some $b>0$: $V$ might, for instance, be the union of tiny pairwise disjoint open intervals around the points $\frac1n$.

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are open nbhds of $0$ and $K$, respectively. Then there is an $a>0$ such that $0\in(-a,a)\setminus K\subseteq U$, and for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $\epsilon_n$ such that $0<\epsilon_n<\frac1n$ and $\left(\frac1n-\epsilon_n,\frac1n+\epsilon_n\right)\subseteq V$. There is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<a$. But then

$$(-a,a)\cap\left(\frac1n-\epsilon_n,\frac1n\right)$$

is a non-empty open interval, so it contains an irrational number $x$, and clearly

$$x\in\big((-a,a)\setminus K\big)\cap\left(\frac1n-\epsilon_n,\frac1n\right)\subseteq U\cap V\,.$$

Thus, $U$ and $V$ cannot be disjoint.